# Changing title of panel in silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am trying to change the title of a panel in silverlight depending on what the user clicks. What I have for the panel controls is

```
<Silverlight_Controls:FloatingPanel 
        x:Name="pnlEntities" 
        Margin="0,0,0,20" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        HorizontalAlignment="left"
        Width="auto"
        Height="200"
        Title=""
        TitleColor="White"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        WindowBackgroundBorder="DarkGray" 
        WindowBackground="DodgerBlue" 
        ContentBackgroundBorder="Transparent" 
        ContentBackground="WhiteSmoke"
        IsCloseButtonVisible="True" 
        IsDraggable="True" 
        IsHeightResizeable="True" 
        IsWidthResizeable="True" 
        IsHeaderVisible="True"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Data:DataGrid 
        </Data:DataGrid>
```

I have the button that I confirm does fire off but it doesn't change anything. I think I am not understanding if something needs to be reloaded or if updatelayout is the wrong thing to call.

```
 private void buttInformation_ExecuteCompleted(object sender, IdentifyEventArgs e)
    {
            pnlEntities.Title = "AreaA";
            pnlEntities.UpdateLayout(); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might be using a custom control.  Find the control that is displaying the text in the title and change the text value of that control.